# Error 424 For VB6 Product on Windows 7, Not XP

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-xp

I created a Visual Basic 6 application that runs without a hitch on my Windows XP machine, though every time I try it on my Windows 7 machine, I receive a 424 (object required) error.

I've tried using compatibility mode and sending the requisite OCXs to the {sys} folder during setup, but to no avail.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OCX files also need to be registered.

Also there is probably a better place for them than the {sys} folder.

Comment: I'm using an old version of Inno Setup. That's always worked (as far as I know) for registering OCXs. Is there a reason it wouldn't for Windows 7? Also, using {sys} sends the OCXs to the SysWOW64 folder in Windows 7, which is the proper folder for such files, no?

Comment: @Rob - Registering files requires elevated privileges on Windows 7. Not familiar with Innu, but I have used an old version of Wise that fails on Windows 7. Also a strange quirk was our application would not run the first time unless run as an administrator. After the first run the app ran fine under the normal user account - go figure.

Comment: It could be the files aren't registered properly on Windows 7 (and are on XP), with this older version of Inno Setup. I am installing as an Administrator, though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I went through the files being registered, one by one, and it looks like the current routine doesn't register one OCX (it does the others) for some reason. It could be I disabled this accidentally.

Comment: That "works after running once as admin" thing is a good sign your installer doesn't work properly.  Also, "registering manually" under a 64-bit OS requires that you run the 32-bit version of regsvr32 (in the SysWOW64 folder), and run it elevated.  Your best bet is to give up on these legacy scripted installers and move to Windows Installer packages instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the 32-bit version of regsvr32"?

Comment: The OCX files MUST go in the location specified by the authors. For MS OCXs, these are more often than not, {sys}. For 3rd party OCXs, use the folder the author specifies. Fo your OCXs, either a subfolder under Common Files or the application folder.

As The location is registered, installing to different locations can very easily cause conflicts and problems.

Comment: @Rob, If you look at the events log you should see which object your application can't find. We've moved most of our ocx and dll files into the applications folder and use the empty text file with the application.exe.local name trick to load the local files. We do need to change installers, but we still have legacy apps that we just make due with until we have the time to update them.